# problem in Laravel to show vueJs component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using VueJs in my laravel blade. i define component to use as a child in one of components ,now component is not defined.

defined component in app.js

```
Vue.component('phoneSearch', require('./components/admin/booking/PhoneSearch').default);
```

my component code :

```js
<template>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "phone-search"
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

and that parent component that i want call child in:

```js
 <template>

    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            name: "add-passenger",

       

        components: {  phoneSearch },
        }
    </script>

    <style scoped>

    </style>
```

finally i got this error in console after run:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: phoneSearch is not defined
at Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./resources/js/components/admin/booking/AddPassenger.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app_admin.js:7878)
at __webpack_require__ (app_admin.js:20)
at Module../resources/js/components/admin/booking/AddPassenger.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app_admin.js:144061)
at __webpack_require__ (app_admin.js:20)
at Module../resources/js/components/admin/booking/AddPassenger.vue (app_admin.js:144025)
at __webpack_require__ (app_admin.js:20)
at Object../resources/js/app_admin.js (app_admin.js:141625)
at __webpack_require__ (app_admin.js:20)
at Object.1 (app_admin.js:144544)
at __webpack_require__ (app_admin.js:20)
```

**anyone can help me?**

Comment: try importing "phoneSearch" component before export default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ashutosh has mentioned, you need to import that component to register it:

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <phoneSearch />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import phoneSearch from './your-directory/your-component.vue';

    export default {
        name: "add-passenger",
        components: {  phoneSearch },
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: just remove from app.js call component directly in parent component and problem solved thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the child component locally inside the parent component to display it

```
 <template>
    <div>
       <your-component></your-component>
    </div>
 </template>

 <script>
      import yourComponent from './components/child-component.vue';

      export default {
                 components: {  yourComponent },
               }
 </script>
```